# How to start Mac OS X client without its window manager Quartz Compositor?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, window-manager

I am planning to install Mac OS X Lion or Mountain Lion into a virtual machine mainly build XCode project. The virtual machine will run on my laptop. Therefore, I am trying to cut down the virtual machine memory usage/improve its performances.

Since I will be building with the xcodebuild command tool, I was thinking of shutting down Mac OS X's Window Manager (Quartz Compositor) to save memory.

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot into [single-user mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492), if the builder does not need the XCode GUI to run. Here are [more details](http://www.westwind.com/reference/OS-X/commandline/single-user.html) about what mounts and services you'd need to perform by hand since single-user mode short-circuits their activations.